# base-derived class relationship

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have this doubt on base-derived class relationship.

i know when we derive an class from the base class, the derived class would have all the information about the base class. but the base class wouldnt know anything about the derived class.

so, why is this acceptable?

```
Base *b=new Derived();
```

and not

```
Derived *d=new Base();.
```

and basically i need to understand the need of the first statement? i mean, what is the use of assigning the derived class object to the base class pointer?

Note : This is not an assignment. im in the early stage  of learning programming. so basically need to understands the bits and pieces. Please ignore if this is very basic and already asked question.

Comment: Keyword: polymorphism.

Comment: because `Derived` is-a `Base`, but not the other way around.

Comment: @chris & Oli Charlesworth : I stand corrected. Comment removed not to confuse people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have answered your own question but I think what is confusing you is the pointer

```
Derived *d=new Base();
```

> derived class would have all the information about the base class. but
>   the base class wouldn't know anything about the derived class.

Yes so you are expecting since this is declaread as derived `Derived *d` it should know everything about base. But what matters is what is actually created. In this case you created Base `new Base();` And `Derived` could have added more to `Base`,  so we cant use Base as Derived.

However in this case

```
Base *b=new Derived();
```

createes a new Derived. But we are only interested on what it inherited from Base. Which is alright.

> Because Derived knows what is in base

.

Answer (score 5):

When the `Derived` class object is made the `Base` class constructor is called first. The `Derived` class object contains the `Base` class object. This allows it to call its `Base` functions. Whereas  a `Base` class object does not contain a `Derived` class object

[image]

```
Base *b=new Derived();
```

is useful  in situations where you can use a single function to handle all derived class objects.

Consider,

Parent class : Animal
Derived classes: Dog, Cat etc

Now, you have a function

`void doSomethingtoTheAnimal(//take Animal here);`

If you were not allowed to assign a base class object to parent reference variable. You will have to create a separate function for `Dog`, `Cat` and so on.

```
void doSomethingtoTheAnimal(Cat *b) or void doSomethingtoTheAnimal(Dog *b)
```

However, with polymorphism you can use `void doSomethingtoTheAnimal(Base *b);` Then you can do

`Base *b1 = new Dog()` or `Base *b2 = new Cat();`

and use the same function `doSomethingtoTheAnimal(b1)` or `doSomethingtoTheAnimal(b2)`

Also, the base class pointer when pointing to a derived class object can only call either the functions in parent class or overriden ones in child class. It is not aware of functions defined exclusively in the child class

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance defines an "is-a" relationship. If `Derived` has `Base` as a base class, then `Derived` is-a `Base`.

In other words : every `Derived` object can be treated as a `Base`, which makes this valid :

```
Base* b = new Derived();
```

Dereferencing `b` allows to access the `Base` parts of the `Derived` instance.

This does not work the other way around, because a `Base` is not a `Derived`. The following is not valid :

```
Derived* d = new Base(); // NOT VALID
```